# Laravel Query Builder Where OR whereIn array

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I am having some trouble in Laravel using the query builder to select users based on two where clauses. 
The first where clause would contain multiple where statements to select a user based on some conditions. If this fails in the OR part I would like to check simply if the user ID is in the array.
Would be grateful for some advice on how I could achieve this.
Thanks.

```
$rs = DB::table('tblUser')
        ->select('name')
        ->where(function($q) {
            $q->where(function($q){
              $q->where('fid', '=', $this->argument('fid'))
                ->where('type', '<', 10)
            })
            ->orWhereIn('id', $userIdSArray);
        })
        ->get();
```

Comment: What isn't working?

Comment: I think there is a problem at `->orWhereIn`. If I just try `->orWhere('id', '123')`; this just runs fine. So there is something wrong on that part.

Comment: What's the result when you replace `->get()` with `->toSql()`? What's the content of `$userIdSArray`?

Comment: `$userIdsArray = ['123', '456'];` I don't get anything if i `dd($rs)` while using `toSql()` in the above

Comment: What Laravel version and database are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$userIdSArray = [ '2', '4', '5' ];
$rs           = DB::table( 'Users' )
                  ->select( 'name' )
                  ->where( function ( $q ) use ( $userIdSArray ) {
                      $q->where( function ( $q ) {
                          $q->where( 'fid', '=', $this->argument( 'fid' ) )
                            ->where( 'type', '<', 10 );
                       })
                       ->orWhereIn( 'id', $userIdSArray );
                  })
                  ->get();
```

I think you need to  pass $userIdSArray in Query builder . And You also forgot (;) after [->where( 'type', '<', 10 )]